# Android File Transfer cannot see a folder created by app

Tags: android, macos, file, transfer

I've installed "android file transfer" on mac.
My app creates a folder and creates a file in it (the permissions exist in AndroidManifest.xml), writes some data into this file.
File exists, I can access it using standard file manager in my android device. It shows many folders, including my folder and I can even see the contents of my file on the device.

But the problem is that "android file transfer" shows me all other folders, but not my folder and my file. I even tried create just a single file, not a directory. Same result.

Unplugging the device or re-launch of "android file transfer" didn't help.

Maybe "android file transfer" is broken tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Maybe "android file transfer" is broken tool?

No.

On Android 3.0+, you need to have your file be indexed by the media scanner before it will be visible over MTP to your Mac. The [static `scanFile()` method on `MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) is your best option IMHO.

Comment: That's a solution. Don't know why it cannot just show everything by default.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar problem. For Android 6.0.1, simply restarting the device solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an easy tool that calls the Android Media Scanner.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.addz.mediascanner&hl=en

Install it on your Android device, run it, and the missing files should show up in Android File Transfer on your computer.